# Paypal - Dynamically change HTML variable for "Buy Now" button?

Tags: php, paypal

I'm new to Paypal integration. I need to **dynamically change the HTML variable** to the `Buy Now` button since I need to calculate `discount_rate` and `shipping`.

At first I use the **hosted button**, but then realized that I can't add new variables.

So I found this alternative way which is **creating our own button**. But then the customer can simply "Inspect Element" and change the value of the `input`.

Is there better and more secure way to implement dynamic pricing for Paypal?

Can I submit the payment through backend script like PHP?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the PayPal express checkout API to create a purchase in the background then send the user to PayPal with a token linked to this purchase.
if you do go down this route, I recommend using this class as it is very simple, yet powerful;
https://github.com/thenbrent/paypal-digital-goods/

On the other hand you can continue what you are doing with the non-hosted buttons and simply check the gross amount paid by the user against what they should have paid in your `notify` script.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I have tried `express checkout` before, but it can't accept credit cards (without paypal account). Or is there option somewhere to enable it?

Comment: I think I remember reading somewhere on PayPal that express checkout can do that, the caveat being it was on the paid version, or something along those lines. Hope this helps.